# How to get all the comments on a subreddit in a tree structure using reddit API?

Tags: python, reddit

For my school assignment I need to get all the comments on last 500 posts in a particular subreddit
with a tree structure. My goal is to find the most used words and make a frequency chart with python.

Using the reddit API I was able to get information about last 500 posts(like title, id, upvotes etc.) on a subreddit but unfortunately I couldn't find how can I get the comments. I have spent my last couple hours searching for this on google but I wasn't able to find anything. Do you have any idea about my problem?

Using other APIs like PRAW and PushShift is forbidden.

I'd be glad if you can help me or at least give me an idea how I can do so

Comment: Please show your attempts at solving the problem so far. Specifically, why are using modules forbidden? What else is forbidden? Beautifulsoup? Selenium?

Comment: I thought about taking every single post id and scraping their links to get the comments but it seemed like too much work. Other than PRAW and PushShift module it is fine to use other modules

Comment: There's no other way to access the comments without opening each post ID

Comment: It is fine for me but the problem is I am searching for last 500 posts so scraping would take much more running time. What do you think I should do?

Comment: I mean, you could use multithreading module or use mapreduce algorithms to improve speed, but you're still going to need to make 500 (or more) API calls to each post